# Saber caracter especifico en arreglo de strings

Tags: c#, array, string

Estoy empezando a programar en C# y me surgió la duda. Cuando uno trabaja con strings uno puede hacer esto:

```
string prueba = "texto";
Console.WriteLine(prueba[2]);
```

Y se muestra en pantalla, en este caso, la letra x. Mi duda es, en un array de strings tal que:

```
string[] comb = {"1234","1342", "1423"};
```

Hay alguna manera de hacer lo mismo, es decir, que se muestre solamente un carácter ya que si pongo:

```
Console.WriteLine(comb[2]);
```

No se haria referencia a un solo caracter sino que al string completo "1423".

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres acceder a los valores que tiene el arreglo un una posición determinada puedes usar ToCharArray(0,2):

```
string prueba = "texto";
        string[] comb = { "1234", "1342", "1423" };
        Console.WriteLine(prueba[2]);
        Console.WriteLine(comb[0].ToCharArray(0,2));
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

La situación es que tu variable comb es un arreglo de strings, es decir una colección o grupo de varias palabras. La forma acceder un carácter específico es primero saber a que string/palabra te refieres. Esto lo puedes hacer con un doble indice, algo así:

```
Console.WriteLine(comb[2][2]);
```

En donde el primer indice, se refiere a que palabra que quieres obtener y el segundo a que carácter que te refieres.

Si deseas investigar más sobre el tema, has una búsqueda para el termino de arreglo multidimensional (en este caso bi-dimensional).